# Samsung Galaxy S features icon backdrops in Launcher, any way to specify it?

Tags: android, icons

I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere. Usually Android app icons feature a transparent background, unlike the squared status quo of the iOS family.

However, the Samsung Galaxy S's launcher sets different icon backdrops for my various apps. On my own app, he attributed a green sunshine, and I see that pattern on some other apps I have installed. The default apps also have various backdrops.

Can I specify what backdrop to show for my app?

Comment: Not sure *how* to do it but it must be possible since Google Maps achieves a custom icon background for its Maps, Navigation, and Places icons.

Comment: Exactly! Knowing how they handle multiple density resources, I'm imagining a picture called something like "icon-backdrop" would work, but no idea what name.

Comment: While it seems to be possible, it might very well be vendor-specific or internal API that is used by built-in Google applications but is not accessible to normal ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galaxy S (as other models by same manufacturer) uses a different launcher.
This is not the default one released with Android AOSP featuring transparent icon background.
This launcher automatically (part of TouchWiz UI) adds a square background to every icon.
There's no way you can do the same without changing it on your phone.
If interested you can download it here http://www.mediafire.com/?n1gtg0mgu2w