# Why there is a blue contour around my application icon which is installed on the Samsung Galaxy tab

Tags: android

I installed my application on a Samsung Galaxy Tab, the application icon has a blue contour around it, does any one know why? other applications installed don't have this blue contour,

I've noticed that all applications created from Eclipse have the same issue

thanks

Comment: I just tried it out on my Tab and it was not-repro. Try updating your s/w?

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by s/w?

Comment: You Galaxy Tab software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has an accepted answer:
[Samsung Galaxy S features icon backdrops in Launcher, any way to specify it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997124/samsung-galaxy-s-features-icon-backdrops-in-launcher-any-way-to-specify-it)

In summary, the Samsung "Applications" launcher does this, and I haven't found a way to customize it.